# I am trying to implement a join table but my variables aren't saving properly. Best advice to refactor this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, crud

I am trying to build out an application where users can post jobs and other users can accept those jobs and for the route to render "complete" after clicking accept job. I have built out a join table to host the multiple responder_users The problem is that my acceptances do not save. Here are my models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    validates :username, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :email, uniqueness: true 
    has_many :acceptances
    has_many :job_requests, :class_name => "Job", :foreign_key => "requestor_user_id"
    has_many :job_responses, :class_name => "Job", :foreign_key => "responder_user_id"
end
```

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :acceptances
    belongs_to :requestor_user, :class_name => "User"
    has_many :responder_user, :class_name => "User", through: :acceptances
end
```

```
class Acceptance < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :job
end
```

And this is the update method that springs from the show page where the accept job is at.

```
 def update
        @job = Job.find(params[:id])
        @acceptance = Acceptance.create(job_id: @job.id, responder_id: @current_user.id)
        @job.acceptances << @acceptance
        if @job.save
            redirect_to jobs_path
        else
            render :show
        end
    end
```

Any help/ advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: The modeling here is really perplexing. I don't get why the Job model is also serving as the record of a request for a user to work on that job or whatever its supposed to be in your domain. I think you really need to first work on the domain model (the tables) and then remove this logic from `JobsController#update` and create a completly separate endpoint to accept job offers. It feels like you're shoehorning like crazy and you have completely missed the fact the `Acceptance.create(job_id: @job.id, responder_id: @current_user.id)` creates an additional code path that must be dealt with.

Comment: Its really one code path to many and violates the SRP as JobsController suddenly has two jobs. Be wary of treating join tables just as plumbing - try to think of them as entities in your domain and create RESTful routes to create, update and destroy them. I would recommend you read up [on nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: Thank you for this max! If you'd like, I answered my own question and added some documentation for this fix and what my overall goal was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came through on the solution for those wracking their brains on something similar. https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/full-stack-ruby-on-rails/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/active-record-associations . This is a great link to further your knowledge hosted by the odin project. Basically, I arranged my models as followed:(job)

```
 belongs_to :requestor_user, :class_name => "User"
    has_many :acceptances, foreign_key: :job_response_id
    has_many :responder_users, through: :acceptances, source: :responder
```

(user)

```
    has_many :acceptances, foreign_key: :responder_id
    has_many :job_requests, :class_name => "Job", :foreign_key => "requestor_user_id"
    has_many :job_responses, through: :acceptances
```

(acceptance)

```
    belongs_to :responder, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :job_response, class_name: "Job"
```

Essentially, the goal here was to figure out how to split two different groups of the same model(in the instance of User & job). From there I was able to host the acceptances in the join table. From there I was able to create a response, as well as a responder for the specific job in my update route.:

```
def update
        @job = Job.find(params[:id])
        @current_user.job_responses << @job
        @job.responder_users << @current_user
        if @job.save
            redirect_to jobs_path
        else
            render :show
        end
    end
```

To show the completion, I simply added some logic in the view for the job:

```
<%if @acceptance%>
<h2>Completed!</h2>
<%else%>
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Accept Job" %>
<% end %>
<%end%>
```

Thank you for those who reached out!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this one..

```
  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @acceptance = @job.acceptances.new(job_id: @job.id, user: @current_user)
    if @acceptance.save
        redirect_to jobs_path
    else
        render :show
    end
  end
```

I find the wording very confusing. Applications might be better, a job has many applications and one application gets accepted. But I hope that helps.

Comment: I wound up changing around my relationships within my models. Thank you for your input anyhow!